# OnCalendar systemd timer unit still executes at boot, how to stop it?

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd, systemd-timer

I have the following unit enabled and started

```
[Unit]
Description=Schedule a nightly execution at 03.15 for Backup ROOT
# Allow manual start
RefuseManualStart=no
# Allow manual stop
RefuseManualStop=no

[Timer]
#Execute job if it missed a run due to machine being off
Persistent=false
# Run every night 03.15
OnCalendar=*-*-* 03:15:00
#File describing job to execute
Unit=schedule-backup@root.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

It will correctly run every night at 3.15am, but it also runs on boot, when it creates a mess! Why is this happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very well answered by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389737/499351) to  [Prevent systemd timer from running on startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363976/97255).

I will summarize

> The problem is that I have always included something like
> WantedBy=basic.target in the [Install] section of the .service file
> (because its part of the standard systemd service copy pasta). It
> turns out this actually causes the unit to be started whenever
> basic.target is (aka system boot).
>
> https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#WantedBy=
> https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#basic.target
>
> TLDR; You do not want an [Install] section in a .service file that is
> triggered by a .timer file.

**As an additional step** you have to disable your service with *systemctl disable [service_name]*

Then you will notice that if you want to enable it again, you cannot and a similar error will be displayed:

Note the part that says

> ... started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer, ...

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

    Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:

• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same trouble. Timer bounded on OnCalendar started every boot.
Timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Samba backup timer
#Requires=samba-backup.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 01:00:00
Persistent=true
AccuracySec=1s
Unit=samba-backup.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Samba backup service

[Service]
#User=root
#Group=root
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/samba-backup.sh
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/samba-backup.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/samba-backup-err.log
```

The timer and service units were placed in the /etc/systemd/system
after I comment *#Requires=samba-backup.service*
everything worked correctly, the timer starts only according to the scheduler time.