# How to avoid systemd periodic realtime timer running at boot

Tags: systemd, services, systemd-timer

I have a realtime timer with `Persistent=false` running immediately after boot although my objective is to run it periodically!
I saw it is a rather common question but none of the answers I found in StackExchange solved my issue. I followed the advices of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680669/oncalendar-systemd-timer-unit-still-executes-at-boot-how-to-stop-it) and [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363976/prevent-systemd-timer-from-running-on-startup/671363#671363).

Here I report a simplified example to reproduce my issue. I want the timer to be executed every 5 minutes (0,5,10,15,...55) but not after boot.

I have the following two files, generated using
`sudo systemctl edit --force --full test.service` and
`sudo systemctl edit --force --full test.timer`

```
# test.service
[Unit]
Description=test

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=echo "TEST"

# test.timer
[Unit]
Description=test

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
Persistent=false

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then I made sure to disable the service using:
`sudo systemctl disable test.service`
and enabled the timer using:
`sudo systemctl enable test.timer`

Now, when running sudo reboot, the `test.service` is immediately executed.
`journalctl -u test` looks like:

```
-- Journal begins at Thu 2023-08-24 02:39:59 UTC, ends at Thu 2023-08-24 19:40:14 UTC. --
Aug 24 19:33:02 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Started test.
Aug 24 19:33:02 rbpi0 echo[463]: TEST
Aug 24 19:33:03 rbpi0 systemd[1]: test.service: Succeeded.
Aug 24 19:35:14 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Started test.
Aug 24 19:35:14 rbpi0 echo[911]: TEST
Aug 24 19:35:14 rbpi0 systemd[1]: test.service: Succeeded.
Aug 24 19:40:14 rbpi0 systemd[1]: Started test.
Aug 24 19:40:14 rbpi0 echo[1352]: TEST
Aug 24 19:40:14 rbpi0 systemd[1]: test.service: Succeeded.
```

And you can clearly see the `test.service` has been executed at `19:33` at boot...

Has someone any Idea where the mistake could be?

## Edit 1

I tried to change the `[Install]` section:

- Attempt 1: Removed completely the `[Install]` section.
  Result:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template units). 
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
```

- Attempt 2: changed `WantedBy=default.target` to `WantedBy=timer.target` or `WantedBy=multi-user.target`
  Result: same issue.

## Edit 2

By reading the [timer manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) I noticed I needed to be sure the system clock is synced before `time-sync.target`. I made sure the clock is synced but the issue remains.

Comment: Try removing the Install section from the timer file. WantedBy=default.target  will cause it to fire  when the system comes up.    I believe the default for a timer with no install is the same as if it had an Install section with After time-set.target and time-sync.target but you should check your system to be sure the system timer is sync'ed before timer tasks are started.

Comment: Your idea is not working for me: when I disable and enable the timer after the I get: `The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

The issue was that I hadn't initialized the time correctly.

Yes I followed [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306410) but I used a script that wrapped the `/sbin/hwclock --hctosys --utc --noadjfile` command, delaying it in time. This let the boot sequence to start already creating a mess with the `OnCalendar=` entry (as described in the [timer manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.timer.html)).

I was enough to add a service exactly as [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306410), no need to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Timer units should have `WantedBy=timer.target` in their `[Install]` section.
2. If you want it to start at a specific point in the boot sequence you should add derictives like `Before=` and/or `After=` etc under `[Unit]` in the timer and/or service units.
3. Not sure what you mean by your differentaion of "realtime" and "periodic" im this context, because timer units are actually both where the `OnCalendar=` makes them "periodic".
4. `*:0/5` means activate every 5 minutes, with no specific starting time hence it starts ASAP after boot, see the output of `systemd-analyze calendar --iterations=10 '*:0/5'`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried everything you proposed but it didn't solve the issue.